# Two PHP Forms that Redirect to x/y URL on the same page

Tags: php, forms, url, redirect, if-statement

I am trying to create a 'simple' redirect for clients who use either Wordpress or Indexhibit to manage there sites.

I have set it up to allow them to input their domain and have it redirect to the respective Admin areas (*I am amazed at how many people forget but hey ho this is my solution*)

I got it working fine for a single redirect but off the back of a previous SO submission tried to integrate both using if / elseif and it fails to Parse.

Any ideas what I have done wrong / help much appreciated!

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['indexhibit_url']) {
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') : $indexhibit_url = $_POST['indexhibit_url']; header('Location: http://' . $indexhibit_url . '/ndxz-studio/');
}
elseif ($_POST['wordpress_url']) {
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') : $wordpress_url = $_POST['wordpress_url']; header('Location: http://' . $wordpress_url . '/wp-admin/');
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="indexhibit_url">

<h3>Indexhibit</h3>

<p class='formp'>If your website is powered by <em>Indexhibit</em> submit your URL to be forwarded to your admin area</p>
<input class='loginforms' type="text"  value='i.e. your-domain-name.com' onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'i.e. your-domain-name.com':this.value;"   name="indexhibit_url" />
<input class="btn btn-info loginbuttons" name="index_submit" type="submit" value="Go" />

</form>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="wordpress_url">

<h3 style='margin-top:2em;'>Wordpress</h3>

<p class='formp'>If your website is powered by <em>Wordpress</em> submit your URL to be forwarded to your admin area</p>
<input class='loginforms' type="text"  value='i.e. your-domain-name.com' onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'i.e. your-domain-name.com':this.value;"   name="wordpress_url" />
<input class="btn btn-info loginbuttons" name="wp_submit" type="submit" value="Go" />

</form>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mixing up ternary and non ternary operators:

just use normal if/else syntax:

```
if ($_POST['indexhibit_url']) {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $indexhibit_url = $_POST['indexhibit_url']; 
        header('Location: http://' . $indexhibit_url . '/ndxz-studio/');
    }
}elseif ($_POST['wordpress_url']) {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $wordpress_url = $_POST['wordpress_url']; 
        header('Location: http://' . $wordpress_url . '/wp-admin/');
    }
}
```

and keep in mind that working with PHP_SELF like this it makes your code vulnerable to xss injections

Comment: Perfect! Yes, I am new to PHP so am still making plenty of errors. But this (coupled with removing <?php endif; ?> from the end of the code makes it work perfectly. Many thanks

Comment: You should use a IDE like netbeans, eclipse and so on for developing to avoid syntax errors.